# Generate RSA coded string from Excel 2007

Tags: vba, encryption, excel-2007, rsa, office-2007

I need to generate RSA encoded string from Excel 2007 document using VBA, but have no idea how to do this(I have public key, string will be decoded in .NET).
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You could solve this another way if you know the code for how to encrypt in .Net.  Then you would create a .Net class with a Encrypt function, expose that class as a COM object and call that function via COM.  This method is often helpful if something is easy using .Net but difficult using VBA or VB6.

Answer (score 2):

[This website](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/crypto.html#dhvb) has a sample for doing it with a module ([basModExp.bas](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/src/basModExp.bas.html))that you need to download.

Then its just calling the method `mpModExp` with the message, the Exponent and modulus (all in baseHex)

Comment: thanks it seems to be working(according to examples in code) but I don`t know how to use it, I really tried but for example for keys 384bits long all examples failed, can you help me pls?